# Junit in Eclipse can not deal with a LinkText apostrophe

Tags: eclipse, selenium, junit, webdriver

A testcase runs in Selenium IDE but when exported to WebDriver and executed in Eclipse the Junit script can not find a LinkText element with an apostrophe in the name.

I escaped the apostrophe but still Junit can not find it.

The line in question is highlighted in the code

I exported a Selenuim testcase that did not contain any apostrophes and I was able to run the WebDriver Junit test in Eclipse without any issues.

I will continue using the testcases without apostrophes but it would be great if I could figure out how to deal with special characters.

Sincerely,

Rick Doucette

```
 import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.junit.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

    public class FirstSelIDEDemo {
      private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;
      private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
      private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.soastastore.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

      @Test
      public void testFirstSelIDEDemo() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Store")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Tron: Legacy")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("product_155_submit_button")).click();
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("product_rating"))).selectByVisibleText("2");
        driver.findElement(By.id("s")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("s")).sendKeys("firth");
        driver.findElement(By.id("searchsubmit")).click();
        *****driver.findElement(By.linkText("The King\'s Speech")).click();*****
        driver.findElement(By.name("product_rating")).click();
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("product_rating"))).selectByVisibleText("4");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form.wpsc_product_rating > input[type=\"submit  \"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("product_160_submit_button")).click();
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("product_rating"))).selectByVisibleText("4");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form.wpsc_product_rating > input[type=\"submit\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("product_160_submit_button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Checkout")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form.adjustform.remove > input[name=\"submit\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span > input[name=\"submit\"]")).click();
        // Warning: assertTextPresent may require manual changes
        assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*ERROR: Please enter a username\\.[\\s\\S]*$"));
  }

  @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape an apostrophe in Java source code, so you can lose the `\`. Is your generated HTML valid (it should have `&apos;` in the source, if it's in an attribute)? Perhaps it's not actually `'` (code u+0027) but something else like u+2019 (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)?